SonarQube Api or -Dsonar.projectDescription and Updating the Project Description Field
Using the webapi or -Dsonar.projectDescription in SonarQube 10.6.x Enterprise Edition, how can I update the Project Description found under Project Information for a project?

I do see sonar.projectDescription under the Analysis-Parameters section and have tried adding this like so -Dsonar.projectDescription=DESCRIPTION within our Jenkins file with no success. We use -Dsonar.projectName=PROJECTNAME just fine however.

I see nothing in the webapi under projects, components or anywhere else for this field. I am able to update tags, so I know my post works:
curl -v -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Content-Length: 0" "https://SONARQUBEURL/api/project_tags/set?project=PROJECTNAME&tags=tagyourit"

Thanks
